# Interpretation of terms in differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics

If I have a differential equation that is of the form,

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f(x,p,t)}{\partial t}=a_{10}\frac{\partial f}{\partial p}+a_{01}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+a_{11}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x\partial p}+a_{20}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial p^2}+a_{02}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}+\cdots\,,
\end{align}

such that the full equation can be represented as (for finite $m$, $n$)
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f(x,p,t)}{\partial t}=\sum_{m,n}a_{m,n}\frac{\partial^m}{\partial p^m}\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}f(x,p,t)\,,
\end{align}

how can I know the physical meaning of an arbitrary derivative of $f(x,p,t)$?

For example, if I look at [Fick's laws of diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick%27s_laws_of_diffusion#), can I then say that my $\partial/\partial x$ and $\partial/\partial p$ terms represent flux in position and momentum respectively, even though there are more terms than single derivatives acting on $f(x,p,t)$?

If this holds true, then the second derivatives would represent diffusion. How would I then interpret mixed partial derivatives or higher order derivatives?